# UNC shared path not accessible though necessary permissions are set

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, permissions, active-directory

I have 2 environments A and B. A is an original environment whereas B is a clone of A, exactly except AD servers. AD server of B has been assigned a trust relationship with A, so that all the service and user accounts of A can be used in B too. And trusting works fine, perfect!!

But I encounter some issues accessing UNC paths(\server2\shared) with these service accounts. I had a check in A environment and all the permissions set in that environment is done in B too (already set since it is a clone of A),but the issue is with B environment only. And FYI, the user is an owner of that folder in both the environments.

I tried creating a folder inside the share(\server2\shared) using command prompt, but failed with error "access denied". What I done a workaround is that I added that user in "security" tab of folder permissions and after that it worked fine. But this was not done in the original  environment.

Is this something related to trust relationship? Why the share to the same location for the same user works differently in 2 environments, though they've been set with the same permissions. FYI, these are windows 2003 servers. Can someone please help.

Comment: What does the Trust have to do with it? Is this a DoaminB user accessing a shared folder in DomainB?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Nope. DomainA user accessing shared folder in DomainB. But set enough permissions as set in DomainA.